# Username doesn't show after using isset

Tags: php

I am learning php new. In the below script after using isset, instead of showing welcome abc, it shows welcome1. Can't understand the problem.  how can i fix it to "welcome abc".any help ?

```
               <?php 
                   session_start();

                $username = isset($_POST['username']);
                $password = isset($_POST['password']);

                if($username == "abc" && $password =="123") {
                    echo 'Welcome' .$username ;
                    echo '<br>';
                    echo '<a href="logout.php">Logout</a>';
                }
                else 
                    die ('wrong password');

              ?>
```

Comment: Works as expected here, https://eval.in/428962. Can you make a reproducible version of this?

Comment: Because `isset()` will return a boolean saying if it is set, this is exactly as expected. But you won't get to the if place using this code ever.

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen could be altered code for here but if that were the case OP would get `wrong password` conditional checks username, `$username == "abc"`

Comment: @chris85 it is altered. Isset will always return a bool.

Comment: @chris85 in your link, it seems ok . but in my pc/browser it's showing welcome1. :|

Comment: @Nazmul I explained in my answer what caused the problem.

Comment: @Nazmul, This can't be you exact code. If it equals `1` it doesn't equal `abc`. If it does equal `abc` then you must be altering it somehow in that conditional.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to print username along with Welcome, you should change your fourth line of code with this one:

```
$username = isset($_POST['username']) ? $_POST['username'] : '';
```

OR

```
$username = $_POST['username'];
```

Your existing code is evaluating an expression which is returning true and that is getting stored in the username, so if you use username as a string it will return as "1".

Comment: it's working now...thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

`Isset` returns `true` or `false` if a variable *is set*, it does not return actual variable data.

In the following code I used ternary operator to return *POSTed* value or an empty string if value was not *POSTed*.

```
session_start();

$username = (isset($_POST['username'])) ? $_POST['username'] : '';
$password = (isset($_POST['password'])) ? $_POST['password'] : '';

if($username == "abc" && $password =="123") {
    echo 'Welcome' .$username ;
    echo '<br>';
    echo '<a href="logout.php">Logout</a>';
}
else 
    die ('wrong password');
```

Answer (score 1):

[`isset()` returns a boolean value](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php).  So you're setting the `$username` and `$password` variables to the values `true` or `false`.  Therefore they will never equal the strings `"abc"` or `"123"`.

Check `isset()` separately from checking the values.  It could be something as simple as this:

```
if (!isset($_POST['username']) || !isset($_POST['password'])) {
    die ('Please supply a username and password.');
}

$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['username'];

// etc...
```

As a side note, the error message "wrong password" is misleading.  First of all, it could have been the username which was wrong as well.  Second of all, never provide an unauthorized user with more information than they already have.  If you tell an attacker that they got a username right and just got the password wrong, you've given them have of the login information.  If anything doesn't match in the login, simply say that the login has failed.

Comment: Thanks for your Help David, Tried your code. its working too. This code is testing purpose that's why i am using that error message. thanks for your sidenote.